# Spring boot mongodb api - Getmapping methods

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, api

In a spring boot - mongodb project, I have a collection with 5 instances:

```
(
 _id,
 courseId,
 userID,
 rating,
 feedback
)
```

In this I want to fetch all `rating` of all documents that have the similar `courseId` which I pass through api key and return them.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query ( a default one, using special name ) or a custom one.

1. `List <YourEntity> findByCourseId(String courseId);`
2. Using this method, you will receive a list of your entities which contains just the rating fields, the rest of them will be set on null.
   Annotate the above solution with:

   ```
    @Query(value="{'courseId' : ?0}", fields="{rating: 1}"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Repository - Taking CustomDocument as the Document with the specified fields.

```java
public interface CustomRepository extends MongoRepository<CustomDocument, String> {
  List<CustomRepository> findAllByCourseId(String courseId);
}
```

Usage

```java
@Service
public class CustomService {

  @Autowired
  private CustomRepository repository;

  public List<CustomDocument> findByCourseId(String courseId) {
    return repository.findAllByCourseId(courseId);
  }
}
```

Actual implementation will be added in runtime for the repository interface. The method naming is used to generate the query. (findAllByCourseId will query by the matching course ID)